# Replace \ character with blank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace \ with blank in pandas series

```
df['Review'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('\','') if isinstance(x,str) else x)[0]
```

But this code is not working. What to change in the code?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the backslash character (`\`) with a blank space in a pandas series, you need to use double backslashes in the string (`"\\"`) because the backslash is an escape character in Python.

```
df['Review'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('\\','') if isinstance(x,str) else x)[0]
```

Also instead of using apply function you can use the `str.replace`

```
df['Review'] = df['Review'].str.replace('\\', '')
```